# Javascript array search engine

Tags: javascript, mysql, search-engine

I have a mysql DB table of about 10.000 rows and about 20 fields. I have a form with all the fields and when I press a key in any of the field it should filter the 10.000 rows to only those that match what I typed. I don't want to make an AJAX request to the server for every key that I type and I was thinking that I can grab all the data at first and make an array out of it and do the search this way. 
My question is: Is this a good way to do it or should I stick with good old SQL queries on the databse and do N ajax requests ? You have a better advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make incremental searches far more efficient just by adding a half-second pause between a keypress and the actual loading of data. The user probably won't notice, but your server will.

Of course, if you can add JavaScript-assisted filtering too, that'd be even better. There's no reason why you can't combine the two methods.

Comment: Also if user pressed new key after those pause you can abort ajax request.

Comment: Exactly. I was going to mention that and then the idea of JS-assistance distracted me from it.

Comment: I already had in mind the thing with aborting the old ajax request if a new one starts. But if the request started ... that means the query to the DB may have already been sent, right ? So it still loads the server. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: With the half-second delay, you can cancel that delay before the AJAX request is sent.